# Magnific-popup - Source (not showing up again) after closing Popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm trying to implement the Magnific-popup on a website. Source is a jquery ( html articles with a header paragraphs...) object loaded as inline type. The shown source is on the same page as the popup. To this point it is working fine, popup is working, content is loaded.

Now I'm unsure whether this is standard behaviour or not: In the background the shown article is hidden, while the rest of the articles are still there. When closing the popup, the shown article stays hidden.

tl;dr: Magnific-popup hides the source of the opened information, not making it visible again after closing the popup.

Am I doing anything wrong or is it just the expected behaviour of Magnific-popup?

Any hints/solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

its general behavior.
when you close the popup once, it adds class "`popup-hide`" to hide the popup content, though which may not be applied by you in its html

i hope you are referring to something like this : http://www.hoopsvilla.com/2014/04/2014-nba-playoffs-bracket-tree-updated-scores-stats-schedule.html (when you click the trigger (the team logo), the inline-content gets hidden once the popup is closed.)

**i'll try to get more (solution) on this later.. :)**